# After adding filter to plugin's code, post's content doesn't display

Tags: filters, the-content

After adding a filter to plugin's code, the post-template.php is not showing the post's content.

This code in plugin's index file:

```
add_filter('the_content','post_add_me');
function post_add_me(){
    $content = 'Test text here';
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Please explain _all filters is not working_ better. I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of [`the_content` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) is wrong. Please check how it should be properly used in the codex in the link supplied

First of all you are totally replacing `the_content` with nothing, that is why you get a blank screen. The reason is that you are not calling the `$content` variable in your function

Secondly, if you've called the variable, you would have replaced all content with *Test text here* as you are overwriting all the content, and not appending it

This should do the job

```
add_filter('the_content','post_add_me');

function post_add_me($content){
    $text = 'Test text here';
    $content = $content . $text;

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem by clicking on the check mark next to my answer. I've noticed that you abandon your questions and leave no feedback. Please help us keep this site constructive by accepting the answers on your previous questions if they solved your problem, and if it did not, feel free to leave a comment to the answer and tell the OP what went wrong. Thanks for understanding. :-)